# Существуют ли сервисы, похожие на codeacademy?

Tags: php

Прочитал большое кол-во ресурсов по PHP, MySQl хотелось бы практикой заняться... Знает ли кто-нибудь сервисы, похожие на codeacademy или где можно выполнять практические задания?

Comment: ну как вариант можно устроиться на работу)

Comment: @DreamChild, я так и делал)

Comment: Придумай проект и начинай делать. Статьи, учебники, советы - все это вторично, главное делать самому, пусть это будет простейший чат - развивай идею, прикрути аякс, добавь кэширование, поиск, фильтры, права... Опыт тем и набивается, что ты постоянно преодолеваешь какие-то технические трудности, совершенствуешь методику и пр. 
А эти ваши "codeacademy" скорее для развлечения, дадут они тебе необходимый навык поиска неполадок? За год интенсивной практики можно освоить в вебе все, что только возможно.

Answer (score 5):

Я думаю сполна отвечу на вопрос одной ссылкой - [Образовательные и обучающие ресурсы для веб-разработчиков и веб-дизайнеров](http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/215487/)